# Tkinter changing the select background color on an unfocused Text widget

Tags: python, colors, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

I am trying to change the default background color for selected text in a Tkinter Text widget on Mac OS X *when the widget does not have focus*. The default unfocused select color is gray. After many hours of searching, I was unable to find an out-of-the-box solution to do this. Here is what I have tried:

- Changing the select color with the `selectbackground` option does not change the select color when the widget is not focused. E.g. It stays gray.
- Nor does `Text.tag_configure("sel", background=...)`
- Using `ttk.Style.map` with the `"!focus"` state works on Entry widgets (and others), but not Text widgets.

So I had to roll my own (see below). Is there a better way to do this?

```python
import Tkinter as tk

# Replace 'tag_out' with 'tag_in'
def replace_tag(widget, tag_out, tag_in):
    ranges = widget.tag_ranges(tag_out)
    widget.tag_remove(tag_out, ranges[0], ranges[1])
    widget.tag_add(tag_in, ranges[0], ranges[1])

def focusin(e):
    replace_tag(e.widget, "sel_focusout", "sel")

def focusout(e):
    replace_tag(e.widget, "sel", "sel_focusout")


root = tk.Tk()

# Create a Text widget with a red selected text background
text = tk.Text(root, selectbackground="red")
text.pack()

# Add some text, and select it
text.insert("1.0", "Hello, world!")
text.tag_add("sel", "1.0", "end")

# Create a new tag to handle changing the background color on selected text
# when the Text widget loses focus
text.tag_configure("sel_focusout", background="green")
replace_tag(text, "sel", "sel_focusout")

# Bind the events to make this magic happen
text.bind("<FocusIn>", focusin)
text.bind("<FocusOut>", focusout)


# Create an Entry widget to easily test the focus behavior
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

entry.insert("0", "Focus me!")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Windows has the opposite problem; by default, there is no inactive selection background.   To make it stay gray on Windows also, Idle has a workaround for this 'bug' that is similar to yours.  Someone recently pointed to `inactiveselectbackground`, so I am removing the workaround today (I wish I had searched SO and found this a year ago).  The option is documented at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/text.htm#M-inactiveselectbackground.  I am considering working on expanding the incomplete tkinter docs.

Answer (score 17):

Digging through the Tk source code lead me to the answer! The `inactiveselectbackground` option sets the color.

```python
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a Text widget with a red selected text background
# And green selected text background when not focused
text = tk.Text(root, selectbackground="red", inactiveselectbackground="green")
text.pack()

# Add some text, and select it
text.insert("1.0", "Hello, world!")
text.tag_add("sel", "1.0", "end")

# Create an Entry widget to easily test the focus behavior
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()

entry.insert("0", "Focus me!")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the priority of the tags using `.tag_lower()` and `.tag_raise()`